# Search Cursor Cannot open Feature Class

Tags: arcpy, cursor, runtimeerror

```
import arcpy

pld3GDB = 'C:\\Users\\bro81520\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\PLDV3_SPC_ODN_315_25Sep.gdb\\PLDV3_SPC_ODN_315_25Sep.gdb\\WO_HIERARCHY'

list = []
fields = ['VENDOR_WO_ID', 'NFID', 'ISFDA']

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(pld3GDB, fields) as cursor:
for row in cursor:
    if row[2] == "Y":
        print(row[1])
del cursor
```

I'm trying to run a SearchCursor on the feature classed titled "pld3GDB', but it keeps giving me the following error:

`Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 8, in <module>
RuntimeError: cannot open 'C:\Users\bro81520\Documents\ArcGIS\PLDV3_SPC_ODN_315_25Sep.gdb\PLDV3_SPC_ODN_315_25Sep.gdb\WO_HIERARCHY'`

I've tried setting the UNC path to `r'C:\Users\bro81520\Documents\ArcGIS\PLDV3_SPC_ODN_315_25Sep.gdb\PLDV3_SPC_ODN_315_25Sep.gdb\WO_HIERARCHY'`,

or

`'C:\\Users\\bro81520\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\PLDV3_SPC_ODN_315_25Sep.gdb
\\PLDV3_SPC_ODN_315_25Sep.gdb\\WO_HIERARCHY'`

But neither works. What could be the culprit here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have written twice the name of the geodatabase. Try removing one.

`\\PLDV3_SPC_ODN_315_25Sep.gdb\\PLDV3_SPC_ODN_315_25Sep.gdb`

```
pld3GDB = 'C:\\Users\\bro81520\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\PLDV3_SPC_ODN_315_25Sep.gdb\\WO_HIERARCHY'
```

[image]

Comment: Deleting the `.gdb` in-front of the folder made it work correctly, not sure why that causes an error?

Comment: @GIS_GOD the way you had it listed in your original question shows a `.gdb` inside a `.gdb` which isn't possible.